# How to uv unwrap a curved pipe?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I've been searching for an answer for how to unwrap curved objects (pipes specifically) in blender.  Youtube throws out tones on how to do it in maya but nothing about it in blender.  If I unwrap this ring with a cap on either side and a seam straight dow, the uv island is really pinched on one side.  Any help?

The other question [How to uv-unwrap a complex bent object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68849/how-to-uv-unwrap-a-complex-bent-object) didnt exactly help massively.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92812/how-can-i-assign-the-texture-on-saturns-rings/

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74515/how-do-i-unwrap-a-cylindrical-object/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74772/uv-unwrap-cylinder-lightsaber-with-extrusions-insets or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23133/unwrap-curved-flat-stripe

Comment: Hi, I've already tried the follow quads but that doesnt seem to work as my quads arent equal and therefore seems to produce alot of stretching and colour change.  I also downloaded the Tube unwrap but that doesnt seem to be active on the list when i hit 'U'

Comment: Might want to check out [Tube UV Unwrap](https://github.com/uhlik/bpy) addon on this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Final:

[image: Final]
[image: final_2]

### Overview:

**Seems:**

This is how I have placed them, not ideal. Seem should be marked along middle edge for a better result. Just count them and select right one.

[image: seems]

**Unwrapping:**

Use my answer from here and don't skip any step. This is crucial.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78362/29370

**Correcting UV:**

Now you should have nice straight UV map.

1. Select middle edge (or edges).

[image: uv_1]

2. Turn on **Proportional Editing** and change **Falloff** type to **Linear**.

[image: uv_1]

3. Move selected edges on X axis to minimise stretching. Don't forget to use Falloff scale - <kbd>MouseWheel</kbd>.

[image: uv_3]

Comment: Thank you so much LukeD! Im still a newbie to unwrapping and didnt realise about proportional editing! Thank you taking the time to help out :)

Comment: @obloquy if my answer was good, please use  accept button and up vote arrow.