# Text on a Curve>Mesh

Tags: text-object

I would like to put the text on the jacket of cable I have rendered. As the Cable itself starts off as a curve which is then converted to a mesh, I need a solution to place it on the mesh and follow it[image]

Comment: Hello :). Is the text an image texture or a mesh object?

Comment: I can do either really. Whatever would be easier. :)

Comment: Well then, why not just UV unwrap the mesh and put the texture there? :)

Comment: I don't know why I did not think of that. Thanks. I'm assuming it will unwrap flat as a cylinder, it won't be a crazy spaghetti mess?

Comment: Yeah, it should work well :). The cable is just a basic cylinder. If you run into any trouble, feel free to ask. Good luck.

Comment: It looks like I already have a problem lol. I have unwrapped and this is the result. 
  https://ibb.co/BNtsHkL . What now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105308/discussion-between-a-b-and-jachym-michal).

Answer (score 1):

Just unwrap the black cable and add the text as an image texture.

1. Add seams to the cable - two around (to cut it from the rest), and one straight (to make it flat).
2. Connect and position the image texture (either by moving the UV or using the *Mapping node*)
3. Done.

*You'll need at least three seams here, to unwrap it flat.*

[image]

Comment: Hi, followed this exactly but got this? https://ibb.co/wwz2jw0

Comment: Hello again :). Yeah, that can happen when unwrapping a bent mesh. [This thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/104600/78972) could help and [this addon](https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares) too. Good luck.

Comment: thanks so much for all your help